# Hadoop's default Grouping comparator?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am trying to understand how the default `grouping comparator` works in Hadoop's MR.

When we don't specify anything in Driver code about grouping `comparator`, does it use `compareTo()` method of the key (assuming Hadoop's inbuilt data type, for example, `IntWritable`).

How about the situations in which we have custom key, does it still depend on key's `compareTo()` method?

I did search online, but I didn't get satisfactory answer to get my doubts clear. Can anyone help clarify this.

## **EDIT**

This question isn't duplicate as has been marked; my question isn't about asking role of grouping comparator, but asking what's the default implemention and for the situation in which we have custom key. I am not sure on what basis this question has been marked as duplicate of the other SO question, which relates to asking the need of "Grouping Comparator". I referred to that question, that is no way related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your queries

> ... does it use `compareTo()` method of the key ....

Yes, but its `compare()` method coming from below implementation

```
public static class Comparator extends WritableComparator
   {
     public Comparator() {
       super();
     }


     public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2)
     {
       int thisValue = readInt(b1, s1);
       int thatValue = readInt(b2, s2);
       return thisValue == thatValue ? 0 : thisValue < thatValue ? -1 : 1;
     }
   }
```

> How about the situations in which we have custom key, does it still
>   depend on key's `compare()` method?

Yes, there is a default implementation available if you would like to optimize.

A sample `writable` type may look like

```
public class MyWritable extends WritableComparator {

    public MyWritable() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
        // Custom code
    }


}
```

From the [doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparator.html), this is an optimization hook. It means, this method is by default implemented, but it should be used for optimization or custom code.

[image]

Please note that there is one more `compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b)`, whcih could be override in case you are using the `WritableComparator(Class<? extends WritableComparable> keyClass)` for implementation.